# Locking an imageview into portrait mode in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView that I want locked on portrait, but a floating menu that I want to change depending on orientation. My thought was that I could just set android:orientation="vertical" in the layout xml, but this does not work as the image is still rotating.

activity_editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/dotted"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/right_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".Editor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only lock an activity to a certain orientation.  This won't be possible with a individual view.

I think your best option is to create another layout for your landscape design, you would add this to layout-land/ folder.

The view would then redraw on rotation the way you have defined it in the other layout.

Comment: So will `android:orientation="vertical"` work after I create a land file or do I need to do something in code?

Comment: you shouldn't need to set an orientation.   The UI will simply follow what is defined in each xml for either orientation